# Where is define codeigniters rewrite rules for recognizing controller,method,id in segment?

Tags: php, codeigniter

how codignitetr recognzes controllername,methodname,id from url like:

https://stackoverflow.com/controllername/methodname/id

Comment: you can check CI routes URI Class

Comment: it is for setting your own routing rules,i want to know where is rule defined for URI segments?

Comment: do you want to check `CI_URI` class?

Comment: for this you can check `_detect_uri()` function in same class

Comment: for more `$this->router->fetch_class()` will return class `$this->router->fetch_method();` will return method and `$this->uri->segment(n)` will return segment

Answer (score 1):

The most used method for this is `CI_URI->segments();`

Read more here: https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/uri.html#CI_URI::segment

> So, each / after your host be different segment.

For example:

```
//http://stackoverflow.com/controllername/methodname/id
echo $this->uri->segment(1); // controllername
echo $this->uri->segment(2); // methodname
echo $this->uri->segment(3); // id
```